# Facing PHP 8 Warning: Attempt to read property "query" on null

Tags: php, properties, null, warnings

Getting a PHP warning for this section of code, whilst running PHP 8:

```
function wpsc_body_class( $classes ) {
global $wp_query, $wpsc_query;

$post_id = get_the_ID();

if ( $post_id ) {

    $page_url = get_permalink( $post_id );

    // If on a product or category page...
    if ( get_option( 'product_list_url' ) == $page_url || get_post_type( $post_id ) === 'wpsc-product' ) {

        $classes[] = 'wp-e-commerce';

        if ( ! is_array( $wpsc_query->query ) ) {
            $classes[] = 'wpsc-home';
        }

        if ( wpsc_is_single_product() ) {
            $object    = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
            $classes[] = 'wpsc-single-product';
            if ( absint( $object->ID ) > 0 ) {
                $classes[] = 'wpsc-single-product-' . absint( $object->ID );
            }
        }

        if ( wpsc_is_in_category() && ! wpsc_is_single_product() ) {
            $classes[]  = 'wpsc-category';
            $tax_object = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
            $classes[]  = 'wpsc-category-' . esc_attr( $tax_object->slug );
        }

        if ( wpsc_is_in_tag() && ! wpsc_is_single_product() ) {
            $classes[]  = 'wpsc-tag';
            $tax_object = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
            $classes[]  = 'wpsc-tag-' . esc_attr( $tax_object->slug );
        }
    }

    $page_url = set_url_scheme( $page_url, 'relative' );

    // If viewing the shopping cart...
    if ( set_url_scheme( get_option( 'shopping_cart_url' ), 'relative' ) === $page_url ) {
        $classes[] = 'wp-e-commerce';
        $classes[] = 'wpsc-shopping-cart';
    }

    // If viewing the transaction...
    if ( set_url_scheme( get_option( 'transact_url' ), 'relative' ) === $page_url ) {
        $classes[] = 'wp-e-commerce';
        $classes[] = 'wpsc-transaction-details';
    }

    // If viewing your account...
    if ( set_url_scheme( get_option( 'user_account_url' ), 'relative' ) === $page_url ) {
        $classes[] = 'wp-e-commerce';
        $classes[] = 'wpsc-user-account';
    }
}

return $classes;
```

}

Error pointing to this line of code:

```
if ( ! is_array( $wpsc_query->query ) ) {
```

Looking for the best way of resolving this, and changing this code, to overcome the php 8 warning for attempt to read property "query" on null.

Answer (score 0):

You should check if the query method exists in the first place and add that check to your if statement like so:

Edit: updated answer to check for null.

```php
        $queryMethodExists = method_exists($wpsc_query, 'query');

        if (
          $wpsc_query === null 
          || ($queryMethodExists && ! is_array( $wpsc_query->query ))
        ) {
            $classes[] = 'wpsc-home';
        }
```

Comment: Thanks A. Pallis. Will give your suggestion a try, and let you know the results.

Comment: Tried the above code, but it caused the following fatal error: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: method_exists(): Argument #1 ($object_or_class) must be of type object|string, null given in (relating to this line of code $queryMethodExists = method_exists($wpsc_query, 'query');

Comment: Hello @James, you need an extra check in that if statement for null as well. I will edit my original answer when i get the chance.

Comment: Thanks A.Pallis, Really appreciate all your time and help on this. Have updated with your amended code, and still getting the same PHP Fatal error.